# How to check remaining items in array?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Imagine I have an array

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

and logic

```
if "one" in arr
  processOne()

if "two" in arr
 processTwo()

if <<there is another items in array>>
  processOthers()
```

What condition should I write in **last** `if`?
I found `_.difference` function, but i don't want to write elements ("one", "two" ...) more than one time.

**EDIT**

1. `if else if else` is not suitable since I need to call 0..N process functions.
2. Here is example with array. But how would this code like if it will be object?
3. array doesn't have duplicates

Comment: What about checking the length and using else?

Comment: `for..in` works with arrays and objects

Answer (score 3):

By using `.indexOf` method.

```
var index;
if ( (index = arr.indexOf('one')) !== -1) {
  processOne();
  arr.splice(index, 1);
}

if ((index = arr.indexOf('two')) !== -1) {
  processTwo();
  arr.splice(index, 1);
}

if (arr.length > 0) {
  processOthers();
}
```

Update: or you could loop the array.

```
var one = false, two = false, others = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] === 'one' && !one) {
    processOne();
    one = true;
  } else if (arr[i] === 'two' && !two) {
    processTwo();
    two = true;
  } else (!others) {
    processOthers();
    others = true;
  }
  if (one && two && others) break;
}
```

Comment: I know how to check element existense. I want to check that there are another items left in array.

Comment: @PlasticRabbit Check my edited answer. If you don't want to change `arr` itself, then make a copy of it.

Comment: I thought about splice function. It is correct. But I think it smells. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this instead:

If you have:

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Then:

```
if (something corresponds to arr[one])
{
  processOne()
}

elseif (something corresponds to arr[two])
{
   processTwo()
}

else (something corresponds to arr[three])
{
   processOthers()
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: if else if else is not suitable.